# How to generate a certain number of rows in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

Need to generate several thousand rows for a specific table in sqlite. All information in the rows will be random. How can this be done quickly?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [**`activerecord-import`**](https://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord-import) gem.

This allows you to insert thousands of record into the database in a single query

Sample usage

```
books = []
10.times do |i| 
  books << Book.new(:name => "book #{i}")
end
Book.import books    # or use import!
```

The above snippet will insert 10 records in books table in a single query

Repository: https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import

**Note**: By random if you mean you need test data you can make use [**`faker`**](https://github.com/stympy/faker) gem

Comment: Just `Book.import([:name], Array.new(10) { |i| "book#{i}" })` is enough.